# Why method is invoked inside Mockito.when creation?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

The method DefaultMessageListenerContainer.isRunning() is called in the Mockito.doReturn(..).when() declaration. Why?

```
@Test
public void isRunning_validParams_isOk() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer mockMessageListenerContainer = Mockito.mock(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.class);
    List<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> internalState = Arrays.asList();
    Whitebox.setInternalState(this.theService, "jmsListeners", internalState);
    try {
        Mockito
            .doReturn(true)
            .doReturn(false)
            .when(mockMessageListenerContainer.isRunning());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Assert.fail("unexpected exception");
    }
    internalState.add(mockMessageListenerContainer);
    boolean result1 = this.theService.isRunning();
    Assert.assertTrue(result1);
    boolean result2 = this.theService.isRunning();
    Assert.assertFalse(result2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your code should be changed to:

```
.doReturn(false)
.when(mockMessageListenerContainer).isRunning();
```

---

When using `doReturn`, the `when` method expects a mock object, more info in the [documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doReturn-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: with this change: 

try {
            Mockito
                .doReturn(false)
                .when(mockMessageListenerContainer).isRunning();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Assert.fail("unexpected exception");
        }

, the error keeps apearing:

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.isRunning(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:347)
 at com.....isRunning_validParams_isOk(RefunderJmsServiceBisTest.java:94)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to the fact that the "isRunning" method is declared as final